# When upload a PNG a noise appears in the thumbnails

Tags: images, woocommerce-offtopic, thumbnails

Since we updated wordpress something strange has happened.
We have a woocommerce where products have different color options for each part of this, and when you select a color, the image with that color appears above the product photo so you can see how it looks.

This has always worked without problem, but since an update the images in a small (mobile) resolution have fine gray lines, and when choosing several colors it is noticed that in the background there are these lines. The problem is not in the photos, so I tried other photos that worked before and now they don't.

This is before adding colors (no lines):
[image: before]

This is what happens when you choose some colors:
[image: after]

Where can be the problem? Thank you for reading.

Comment: I guess this ImageMagick or GD resizing the image and isn't really WordPress's fault. Is the background definitely totally white? Can you resize the image with ImageMagick or GD (which one are you using?) manually and get the same effect?

Comment: The answer is no, it's not totally white: you have a mix of 255,255,255 and 254,254,254 in a quick square in the middle I looked at. Quite why that's being rounded up into a visible grey I don't know. But you could try processing the image to remove that, and catch any other nearly-but-not-quite whites in the affected spaces?